# How to know if an OracleConnection coming from the connection pool was used before

Tags: oracle, ado.net, oracle11g, connection-pooling, odp.net

My application needs to authenticate all session on the DB via a trusted procedure (that sets some values in the session context). Currently this procedure is called for each new session just after it is opened.

I'd now like to improve this by removing unneeded round-trips. Connections from the connection pool which were used (and authenticated) before don't need to call the procedure again because the session context variables are still set on the server.

But I can't find a way to identify reused connections. Is there any way (which of course doesn't need a round-trip too)?

Architecture: Multiple client applications use the same DB account (a read-only account with synonyms to the real schema) to connect. After the connection it is required that each new session calls an authentication procedure to set some session context variables. These context variables are checked on select/insert/update/delete by Oracle FGAC (virtual private database).

My code:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
conn.Open();

if (true) { // TODO: Identify not yet authenticated connections.
   using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("authentication.login", conn)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("i_user_id", OracleDbType.Int64).Value = _userId;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("i_role_id", OracleDbType.Int64).Value = _roleId;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Comment: @KevinBurton I've edited my question to show that I need to pass data (userId and roleId) to the DB for authentication. The authentication procedure checks the given ids (and some other things) before it sets the context variables.

Comment: @KevinBurton What user name? Do you mean the id? This id can only change if the user decides to switch to another user (account). Then I call the authentication procedure again to set the new values in the session context. There will never be more than one active user (account) per process/connection pool.

Comment: No, sorry, there was some misunderstanding. It is a multi user system. The single user is only per client process/thread pool. So multiple users can start the app the same time, but there is only one user per app. I've edited my question with an architecture description.

Comment: I've tested it, I don't need to call the authentication method if the session was authenticated before. Connections in the connection pool are still known on the server and don't loose their session context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer that clearly states that this isn't possible: [ODP.NET connection pooling: How to tell if a connection has been used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845559/odp-net-connection-pooling-how-to-tell-if-a-connection-has-been-used/7937547#7937547)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a connection pool for your oracle connections.
And each connection you create could be inserted with a some key (using `conn.setSessionInfo(key)`) that can be verified later when you get the connection back.

The key can be a any thing of your choice or maybe a hashkey you generate.

Comment: What do you mean with "create a connection pool"? There is already a connection pool which is created by ODP.NET. `SetSessionInfo()` expects a `OracleGlobalization` object as parameter, not a key. Maybe you meant `ClientInfo`? But that is a set-only property, so how can I verify it later?

Answer (score 1):

You should clear all contexts and reset all packages anyway when you get a connection from a connectionpool. Add this authentication to your initialization.

[Preparing an Oracle Connection after being retrieved from a ConnectionPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350106/preparing-an-oracle-connection-after-being-retrieved-from-a-connectionpool/51351433#51351433)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not clear what your authentication is doing - verifying that the connection comes from your app? - and whether you're passing anything to your procedure. Could you consider using a [logon trigger](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/app_context.htm#DBSEG60634) to call your procedure from the DB side, only for the user your pool is using, as the session is created?

Comment: I've edited my question to show that I need to pass data (userId and roleId) to the DB for authentication. The authentication procedure checks the given ids (and some other things) before it sets the context variables.