# ODP.NET connection pooling: How to tell if a connection has been used

Tags: c#, oracle, connection-pooling, odp.net

I'm modifying a Winforms app to use connection pooling so data access can occur in background threads. The business logic is implemented in PL/SQL and there are a couple of security related stored procedures that have to be called in order to make use of the business logic.

What I need is a way to tell if the connection has been used without a round-trip to the database. I don't think I can keep track of them in a `HashSet` because I doubt `Equals` or even `ReferenceEquals` could be relied upon. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, I plan to use ODP.NET's built-in connection pooling mechanism. If I rolled my own connection pool, keeping track of which connections were new vs. used would be extremely trivial.

Comment: Go the route that's 'extremely trivial'.. why would you do anything else?

Comment: By that I mean, you don't want to reinvent the wheel, but then clearly state you want to reinvent the wheel. :) [or, part of the wheel].

Comment: Am I not being clear? I don't want to re-invent the **connection pooling** wheel. I just want to know if a connection has already been established to save time doing some per-connection business logic API initialisation code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection pooling provided by ODP.NET is completely opaque. That is, it isn't leaky in the way I'd like it to be - there is no way of knowing if a connection has been used before or is brand new. However it is a leaky abstraction in another way: Any session state (e.g. package scoped variables, which are session scoped) is preserved between usages of the connection. Since this is a question about determining the used vs. new state of a connection **without going to the database**, the answer is that it simply cannot be done using ODP.NET's built-in connection pool.

That leaves two options:

1. Create a connection pool implementation that either provides that information or performs user-defined initialisation upon creation of each new connection; or
2. Perform a round-trip to the database to determine the used vs. new state of the connection.

Comment: For the record, I built a general-purpose object pool that outsources object creation to a factory which is injected into it. I recycled my existing Oracle connection factory which already contained the setup code. It works perfectly.

Comment: 2 other alternatives: ensure that your connections are always left in a known state (You can probably leverage `using` plus `IDisposable`s to undo any changes to the connection you do.) **or**, if your situation allows it, just unconditionally redo any set up operations.

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET manages a connection pool for you. It's even configurable. Why would you ever try to track these connections yourself?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543.aspx

And, specifically for Oracle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502.aspx

> The .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle provides connection
>   pooling automatically for your ADO.NET client application. You can
>   also supply several connection string modifiers to control connection
>   pooling behavior (see "Controlling Connection Pooling with Connection
>   String Keywords," later in this topic).
>
> Pool Creation and Assignment
>
> When a connection is opened, a connection pool is created based on an
>   exact matching algorithm that associates the pool with the connection
>   string in the connection. Each connection pool is associated with a
>   distinct connection string. When a new connection is opened, if the
>   connection string is not an exact match to an existing pool, a new
>   pool is created.
>
> Once created, connection pools are not destroyed until the active
>   process ends. Maintaining inactive or empty pools uses very few system
>   resources.

BTW, I guess I'm not totally hip on all the OracleClient changes that have been going on. It seems like Microsoft may be dropping support? Last I knew ODP.NET was based on ADO.NET... but, even if I'm mistaken about that, ODB.NET claims to support connection pooling out of the box as well:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/featConnecting.htm#CJAFIDDC

Comment: Yes, I plan to use the built-in connection pooling provided by ODP.NET. Otherwise (if I rolled my own) I would know exactly when I'm creating fresh connections vs. dishing out one that has already been initialized.

Comment: I think the question Steve is asking is, what is the advantage you get by manually keeping track of your connections in the connection pool when it is already taken care by the provider (ODP.NET)? As such you just need to keep using your business logic and other code as it is and the pooling is transparent in the background.

Comment: It's not transparent, it's opaque. If it was transparent, I could actually see if the connection has been used previously.

Comment: What difference does it make, since you have no control over what connection you're going to get out of the pool anyways?

Comment: I know I have no control. I don't need control. I just want to **know** if the connection has been used before.

Comment: If you're relying on determining the state of a connection (authenticated/unauthenticated) based on whether or not it has been used before, I think you're really setting yourself up for a miserable time.

Comment: @Steve: Not the OP, and for a different system, but in SQL Server 2000, you can't change app roles once you've done so. If you try, even to change to the SAME app role, you get an exception. So, either no pooling, or you need to know whether the app role has been set on the connection. You could of course handle this by handling the exception created when you try to do something without permission, but that's not a good way to handle things either.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to just know whether you ever had some connections not come from pool but a fresh new one, I think that you can use the HardConnectsPerSecond and SoftconnectsPerSecond performance counter provided by ODP.NET.

This won't tell you exactly which OracleConnection.Open() leads to a hard connection, though. I was also thinking about combining other ODP.NET perf counter to determine if a new hard connection is created, but after some experiments this is not easy because ODP.NET will also purge connections every three minutes (depending on the Decr Pool Size setting).