# Preparing an Oracle Connection after being retrieved from a ConnectionPool

Tags: oracle

I understand that after getting a connection pool I should clear state from all the packages with a call to

```
sys.DBMS_SESSION.reset_package;
```

Furthermore the contexts are supposed to be cleared, however, contexts have a namespace.

Am I supposed to find every namespace and clear each of them?

How do I find all of the namespaces?
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e16543/app_context.htm#CIHDAJDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dbms_session.list_context`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sessio.htm#i1010363) to get the list of existing contexts for the current session.

Answer (score 0):

Then it would seem appropriate to call this with every connection returned from a connection pool.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prepare_connection
AS
  context_info DBMS_SESSION.AppCtxTabTyp;
  info_count PLS_INTEGER;
  indx PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_SESSION.LIST_CONTEXT ( context_info, info_count);
  indx := context_info.FIRST;   
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN indx IS NULL;
    DBMS_SESSION.CLEAR_CONTEXT(
      context_info(indx).namespace,
      context_info(indx).attribute,
      null 
    );
    indx := context_info.NEXT (indx);
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE;   
END;
/
create public synonym prepare_connection for prepare_connection;
grant execute on prepare_connection to public;
```